# Submit div content contains form control states

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization, dynamic

I have a `div` with HTML tags and form controls like `check boxes, text and drop lists`. I want to post the whole content along with form controls' states (ie, capture user's choices) to save it into database and later, re-render the exact HTML.

How can I do that? I used

`$("#div").clone()`

But it seems control states not saved.
Note: I don't want to post the inner form, then re-render form states because the HTML is dynamic (it's a HTML template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you need to store control states into HTML elements first (to a markup) and then submit div's innerHTML property...

See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/esy1cc8z/

First of all you need to iterate over all form controls in specified DIV:

```
var ctrls = parent.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea");

for(var i = 0; i < ctrls.length; i++){
    var el = ctrls.item(i);
    //...
```

And then store states of various form controls into DOM elements as attributes (= default values in HTML):

```
var type = el.getAttribute("type");
//For checkbox

//Checkbox
if(type == "checkbox"){

    if(el.checked)
        el.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    else
        el.removeAttribute("checked");

//Other textual / numeric input types
} else {

    el.setAttribute("value", el.value);                 

}
```

Of course if you need usable algorithm then you need to write conditions for all form control types, this is just an example...

Note: this is pure JS solution, using jQuery it may be simplier code...

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to be more examplary and clones entire div controls into new div with control states - http://jsfiddle.net/esy1cc8z/1/

Comment: Your solution works for me, very much appreciate, Jiri, you're the man.